# Iterating with v-for on dynamic item

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to iterate through a db object I fetch during created(), I get the values in a console.log but the v-for template part remains empty. My sub-question is : is this good practice ? I'm quite new to Vue and my searches on this issue make me think it's a lifecycle issue.

Thanks for the help.

TEMPLATE PART :

```
 .content(v-for="(content, key, index) in contents")
   h3 {{key}}
   .line
   | {{getValue(content)}} // this is blank
```

METHODS PART:

```
getValue(value) {
  PagesService.fetchDataWrap({
    id: value
  }).then((response) => {
    const test = response.data.values[0].value
    console.log(test) //this is working and gives the right value
    return test
  })
},
getPage() {
  PagesService.fetchPage({
    id: this.$route.params.page
  }).then((response) => {
    this.name = response.data.result.name
    this.langs = response.data.result.langs
    this.project = response.data.result.parent
    this.contents = response.data.result.values
  })
  this.getProject()
}
```

console.log(this.contents) result :

```
{__ob__: Observer}
footer: "5a29943b719236225dce6191"
header: "5a29a9f080568b2484b31ee1"
```

which is the values I want to send when v-for iterates on contents so the getValue can process it to fetch corresponding values

Comment: When / where do you call `getPage()`? Not seeing any reason for you to use `async` / `await` either. Your methods don't return anything or rely on asynchronous operations to complete

Comment: `getPage()` is called in the `created()` part of the component, my methods do return the right values.

Comment: No they don't. In fact, they don't return anything

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, sorry. I tried to put in async to test if it would make a difference but even without, I still have the same result : good values shows up in console.log but not in the template

Comment: Can you show an example of the value of `contents`? Have you added `console.log(this.contents)` in `getPage()` after you assign a value to check that it is set correctly?

Comment: I edited the post with the console.log from content and removed async, the whole script seems to work as the console.log(test) in getValue have the right values but the return is still not sending it's value in the v-for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend attempting to output the value of an asynchronous method. It's highly unlikely that it will work correctly.

Instead, populate your `contents` array / object **fully** during the `created` hook. For example, this can replace the `contents` hash value with whatever comes back from `fetchDataWrap`...

```js
getPage () {
  PagesService.fetchPage({
    id: this.$route.params.page
  }).then(response => {
    this.name = response.data.result.name
    this.langs = response.data.result.langs
    this.project = response.data.result.parent

    let contents = response.data.result.values
    Promise.all(Object.keys(contents).map(key => {
      // map each key to a "fetchDataWrap" promise
      return PageService.fetchDataWrap({
        id: contents[key]
      }).then(res => {
        // replace the hash with the resolved value
        contents[key] = res.data.values[0].value
      })
    }).then(() => {
      // all done, assign the data property
      this.contents = contents
    })
  })
}
```

---

Then you can trust that the content has been loaded for rendering

```
.content(v-for="(content, key, index) in contents")
  h3 {{key}}
  .line
  | {{content}}
```

Comment: Wow ! I tried this `Promise.all` before trying my solution but never got it to work ! Thanks a lot for the help, it got me a whole bunch of understanding on Vue.